# как настроить gradle для тестирования?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, gradle, junit

код лежит в двух модулях dev и main. Тесты лежат в модуле test. Проблема в том, что в тестах не видит классы. Пробовал настроить след образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас `dev/src/` вместо `dev`

Answer (score 0):

добавил в

```
dependecies {
    testCompile sourceSets.dev.output
    testCompile sourceSets.main.output
}
```